# Uniqueness constraint feature requires ios deployment target 9.0 or higher - Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode7

IOS 9 has a useful feature where you can add a unique constraint on a property. [IOS 9 unique constraints](http://dorianroy.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-implement-unique-constraints-in-core-data-with-ios-9/)

However I want to support IOS 8 upwards and cannot compile unless I set my deployment target to 9.

Is there a way I can create two data models and at a compiler directive to use data model **A** with **IOS 8** and data model **B** with **IOS 9** and up ?

----- update --------------------

Below the code I used to add the unique constraint manually

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CL" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
        NSArray *entities = [_managedObjectModel entities];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [entities firstObject];
        NSArray *properties = @[@"serverFileId"];
        [entity setUniquenessConstraints:@[properties]];
    }
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

Comment: can you create two different Models and use it per-iOS to create ManagedObjectContext ?

Comment: I got it. It will not be possible to package the app this way for both iOS 8 and 9 :(

Comment: do you want to check for uniqueness in iOS 8, or do nothing?

Comment: @wain For IOS8 and IOS9 we need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite an interesting question, Ryan. The only solution that comes up to my mind is:

- You create an iOS8+iOS9 compliant model (w/o the uniqueness
  constraints).
- You guard some part of your persistent store coordinator creation code with

`if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { // add uniqueness constraints here }`

- You add the uniqueness constraints within the guarded scope programmatically like described
  [here](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/creating-a-coredata-model-in-code/).

**Update:**
I've been looking for a way to apply uniqueness constraints to a property programmatically and have ended up with a piece of `CoreData.NSEntityDescription`'s class definition. Here goes the desired piece of code:

```
/* Returns/sets uniqueness constraints for the entity. A uniqueness constraint is a set of one or more attributes whose value must be unique over the set of instances of that entity.
    Returns/sets an array of arrays, each of which contains one or more NSAttributeDescription or NSString instances (strings must be the names of attributes on the entity) on which the constraint is registered. 
    This value forms part of the entity's version hash. Stores which do not support uniqueness constraints should refuse to initialize when given a model containing such constraints.
    Discussion: uniqueness constraint violations can be computationally expensive to handle. It is highly suggested that there be only one uniqueness constraint per entity hierarchy,
    although subentites may extend a sueprentity's constraint.
*/

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public var uniquenessConstraints: [[AnyObject]]
```

Comment: I think this is the correct approach, I am looking for code on how to add a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: @RyanHeitner, please consider the update on my answer - there might be what you wanted to find.

Comment: Oh, you should have put the ObjC tag, so that I knew. Anyways, glad to know it works.